# post method not working without any error

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating a simple crud operation using angular and asp.net core webapi.When i try with value to post value it is not working.

post component:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<form (ngSubmit)="validateuser()" #homeForm="ngForm">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="address">User Name</label>
  <input type="text "  min="0" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="datas.username" name="username" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="address">Password</label>
  <input type="text "  min="0" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="datas.password" name="password" required>
</div>
</form>
<div class="form-group">
  <button type="submit"    class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!homeForm.form.valid">login</button>
</div>
</div>
```

service :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { UrlResolver } from '@angular/compiler';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  datas= {};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  validateuser() {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:7254/api/user/token',this.datas)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.router.navigate(['/homes']);


        }, (err) => {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }

      );
      }
    }
```

API Conroller:

```
namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/User")]
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ModelItemContext _context;

        public UserController(ModelItemContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost("{token}")]
        public ActionResult CreateToken([FromBody] User item_2)
        {
            var item_1 = _context.User.FirstOrDefault(t => t.UserName == item_2.UserName && t.Password == item_2.Password);
            if (item_1 == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            _context.User.Update(item_1);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return new NoContentResult();
        }


    }
}
```

When i try with debug point . the value not hit to angular service file. what is wrong here.please give me idea.The same method working for create user . but not working when i check with password and user name.

Comment: Can you show your controller more? It would be helpful to see all of the parts of the controller that make up the API's available endpoints.

Comment: i added as api conroller

Comment: That's just the Action need to see the route attribute on the Controller.

Comment: something like this [Route("api/[controller]")] and the Class declaration too

Comment: do i need to paste full contoller class

Comment: Couldn’t hurt 

Comment: added controller

Comment: you are telling that in validateuser() values are there in this.datas but in API controller User item_2 is null or empty?? Am i right??

Comment: no. when i input validateuser not getting the value from my input

Comment: it is not hit the angular service file. not problem with controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your **data variable** is empty object. Hence declare the **data variable** as shown below,

```
datas: any = {
  username: '',
  password: ''
};
```

And the post URL from UI should be like,
**'http://localhost:7254/api/User/token'**

And change your **CreateToken** method in API like,

```
[Route("token")]
public ActionResult CreateToken([FromBody]User item_2)
{

}
```

**Note: In HTML, add the button inside form tag.**

**Note:** User model in API should match with the angular model.

Comment: Did you added the button inside form tag?

Comment: it is working naming error with backend and frond end. thank you